# Web scraping - selection of a table

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to extract [the table of historical data](http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EFTSE/history?period1=946684800&period2=1470441600&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo) from Yahoo Finance website.

First, by inspecting the source code I've found that it's actually a table, so I suspect that `html_table()` from `rvest` should be able to work with it, however, I can't find a way to reach it from R. I've tried providing the function with just the full page, however, it did not fetch the right table:

```
url <- https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^FTSE/history?period1=946684800&period2=1470441600&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo
read_html(url) %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
# Returns only:
# [[1]]
#                                                               X1     X2
# 1 Show all results for Tip: Use comma to separate multiple quotes Search
```

Second, I've found an xpath selector for the particular table, but I am still unsuccessful in fetching the data:

```
xpath1 <- '//*[@id="main-0-Quote-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/section/div/section/div[3]/table'
read_html(url) %>% html_node(xpath = xpath1)
# Returns an empty nodeset:
# {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

By removing the last term from the selector I get a non-empty nodeset, however, still no table:

```
xpath2 <- '//*[@id="main-0-Quote-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/section/div/section/div[3]'
read_html(url) %>% html_node(xpath = xpath2) %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
# Error: html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I've found that `html_text()` with the last xpath returns

```
read_html(url) %>% html_node(xpath = xpath2) %>% html_text()
[1] "Loading..."
```

which suggests that the table is not yet loaded when R did the read. This would explain why it failed to see the table. Question: any ways of bypassing that loading text?

Comment: There are functions for querying the Yahoo Finance API directly like `quantmod::getSymbols` which are probably a much better way to solve this problem.

Comment: @alistaire it does work for most of the symbols, however, ``getSymbols('FTSE', src = 'yahoo')`` returned an error.

Comment: The symbol should be `'^FTSE'`, but it's still not working, which is odd, as it works for other indices like the S&P and DAX. I did notice the Yahoo query of your URL for some reason lacks a download link, which they usually have. Honestly, as it's now a very different question, you may want to re-ask tagged with `quantmod` so you can attract the right attention.

Comment: @allistaire Those are almost certainly licensing issues. I don't see how this is related to quantmod.

Comment: @RHertel as you mention now, it does seem as licensing issues indeed - even selecting and copying the data by mouse from the web is disabled for FTSE, while it works for other symbols. Also, I remember there used to be a .csv download link for this symbol just like for other symbols at least a month ago. Any ideas how to get (or whether it is possible to get) the proper licenses for viewing/using the data?

Comment: @Nutle I have searched a while and could not find anything except for a few offers by commercial data providers. For example, Quandl is referring to barchart.com (https://www.quandl.com/data/BCIW/_FTSE-FTSE-100-Index-FTSE). It seems like the EOD data of FTSE100 is no longer freely available.